# Hive 0.14 - Hbase 0.98.8 Integration Issue

Tags: hive, hbase, hadoop2

I want read data from HBase by means HIVE CLI.
I start hive with following  command

```
bin/hive --auxpath /usr/local/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-0.14.0.jar , /usr/local/hive/lib/hbase-common-0.98.8-hadoop2.jar , /usr/local/hive/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar , /usr/local/hive/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar , /usr/local/hive/lib/hbase-protocol-0.98.8-hadoop2.jar , /usr/local/hive/lib/hbase-server-0.98.8-hadoop2.jar -hiveconf hbase hbase.master=masternode:60000 hive.root.logger=INFO,console hbase.zookeeper.quorum=localhost:2181
```

and I run the following query

```
hive> CREATE TABLE table1(key int, value string)                      
    > STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'    
    > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:name")
    > TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "emp2");
```

but I receive this error

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin
```

What's the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue adding hbase-client-0.98.8-hadoop2.jar to classpath in command line. Neverthless I have now this exception

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:MetaException(message:java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.getHBaseAdmin(HBaseStorageHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.preCreateTable(HBaseStorageHandler.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:90)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.createTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3959)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1004)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:616)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:411)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/cloudera/htrace/Trace
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(HConnectionManager.java:839)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:642)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.cloudera.htrace.Trace
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 45 more
)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.getHBaseAdmin(HBaseStorageHandler.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.preCreateTable(HBaseStorageHandler.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:90)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.createTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3959)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1004)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:616)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
)
```

It works because I've added htrace-core-2.04.jar in my classpath.